# Is that possible to run validation code before Populating Spring @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i have spring MVC controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/user/limits" })
public class UserController {

    @Value("${wsgServiceURL}")
    private String wsgServiceURL;
    .
    .
```

which populate `wsgServiceURL` value from property file

is that possible to run validation code on that value before population

Comment: What kind of validation do you want to perform? Only check if the value is set or not or more complicated stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like the below,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/user/limits" })
    public class UserController {

        private String wsgServiceURL;

        @Autowired
        public void initProperty(@Value("${wsgServiceURL}") String wsgServiceURL) {
            if(wsgServiceURL== null) {
                // Error handling here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the current code working very well, i just need improve it as i have injected many variables and validating each one individually, i want to centralize the validation code and run it for every injection

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible using type safe configuration properties through the [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)mechanism

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/user/limits" })
@ConfigurationProperties("uc") 
public class UserController {
     // will map to uc.wsgServiceURL in property file
    private String wsgServiceURL;
```

You can also add validation with [@Validated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-validation) and use use JSR-303 javax.validation

Comment: is ConfigurationProperties annotation is available in spring MVC. i don't use spring Boot

Comment: I think ConfigurationProperties is Spring boot code only.